# Adblocker blocks Analytics Code

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the following code, unlike old GA codes(*which are different too*), the following code is blocked by my own browser `uBlock Origin` plugin. My other GA codes are not blocked despite of Ad Blocker is there, I tried to to use Old code for new ID but that did not work either

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-50334670-6"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-6');
    </script>
```

I tried to put code both in `<head>` and `<body>` but no use.

Comment: Your snippet is served from `googletagmanager.com` which then further loads JavaScript from `google-analytics.com`.   If your ad blocker blocks either of those two origins you will have problems.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller my concern is not my browser but my site visitors.

Comment: *"my concern is not my browser but my site visitors"* If you are concerned about site visitors, why not drop the creepy third-party tracking and just review server logs? You can use something like GoAccess if you need graphs or weekly reports to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Ive used this plugin in the past and in the plugin dashboard you have a 3rd party filters tab.

one of the **Privacy** filters is blocking the analytics, check which filter is and deactivate it.

Update: Try to deactivate the:uBlock filters - Privacy

Here is a list from quontable with adblocks:

[image: picture from quontable.com]